# isight not working, lost it after upgrade

Tags: macos, skype, isight

right now i am running the OS X Yosemite 10.10, after upgrading my OS X i lost my camera, i tried everything in the forums, but nothing helped.

i can't FaceTime, or Skype or anything. normally i would take it in to an apple store, but the closest apple store to me is about 200 miles away.

i also installed the update 2 days ago as it was recommended in the app store.

(not a hardware problem, was working perfectly before the upgrade and it is not found in the "system info> USB"); also not user specific.

really need the camera please help, and i posted this on stack overflow and was told to post here.